Mixing of two same gas
If two same gas separated by a membrane and after removing it would it mix
What i think is that if the particles of same gas separated by a membrane why would they mix if mixing of them would not lead to increase in entropy or entropy will be constant so will the gas molecules mix or the molecules at one side will stay at what side they are

Of cause they mix, since they move! but you will have trouble proving it!

This question is similar to: What is the resolution of the Gibbs paradox?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
